# How do you remove a "duplicate" label from a question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I found this question for Python programming:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286554/time-delay-between-each-step-python?answertab=oldest#tab-top

It was marked as a duplicate of this question:

[Can the execution of statements in Python be delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327775/can-the-execution-of-statements-in-python-be-delayed/3327782#3327782)

My issue is that I feel the second question does not have any answers to the one marked as a duplicate, even if they are very closely related.

Now that I've explained the situation, I want to know if there is a way to change the duplicate status of questions like this.

Comment: You don't not without voting to reopen it.

Comment: @Nathan wrong duplicate. The one you found is about question which only got pending flags/votes but not yet closed.